# Is Erlang VM Creates single thread for each hardware core of the CPU?

Tags: performance, erlang, cpu, multicore

Does Erlang vm runs on single system thread for one hardware core? If not then what is the advantage of multi core?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, BEAM (Erlang VM) creates one thread for scheduler per core (or value set by `+S` switch) and one dirty CPU thread per core (by default since R20 and value can be changed by `+SDcpu`) and 10 async I/O pool threads by default (change by `+A`) and 10 dirty I/O threads (since R20, change by `+SDio`). You can bind scheduler threads to physical cores using `+sbt` flag (use `+sbt db` for default bind). You can set CPU topology if detected wrong using `+sct` flag.

You could find out yourself by easy peek to the documentation. [`erl`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html)